Blocked funds on Solanabeach
Good afternoon, my name is Rosalía Sánchez Tornero Minaya, and on Friday at 7:40 pm I sent my Gamestock funds from my Phantom wallet (Solana account), and they are blocked in Solanabeach.io.
When am I going to received them, please?.
The transaction is listed as Successful, and money is moving.
I would appreciate it if you could send it to me as soon as possible to my Solana account in my Phantom wallet. I just need my money back.
I send you the account and the Signature.
Solana account (Phantom Wallet): BxNS9ARQuyJVNHWe93R9rWwZCBuq7ipJGxjyT8tZShhQ
Signature: 4r5fHnpr99Po4iiC7GdL8JkmpxnbYwP5p1JjwXywJsiM7dtD2CQxQVXSgPtsWorBrARP4b3o74CsuEBUZGB8xfS6
Thank you.
Sincerely.
Rosalía
